# hevc_nvenc recording stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, video, hevc

I am usually doing screen recordings with SimpleScreenRecorder and using the hevc_nvenc setting as it allows me to utilize my GPU when recording 4K screens. After my upgrade to 18.04, I noticed that the videos are unusable now. I created a short clip to show the effect -->
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMB06JJeeFU&feature=youtu.be)

The problem is not correctable when converting with ffmpeg. These are the errors ffmpeg gives me:

```
[hevc @ 0x563a203a80a0] Duplicate POC in a sequence: 9.
[hevc @ 0x563a203a80a0] Error parsing NAL unit #1.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[hevc @ 0x563a203a80a0] Could not find ref with POC 541.74 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed= 2.5x    
[hevc @ 0x563a202fa9e0] Duplicate POC in a sequence: 55.
[hevc @ 0x563a202fa9e0] Error parsing NAL unit #1.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[hevc @ 0x563a20473980] Could not find ref with POC 69
[hevc @ 0x563a20484500] Duplicate POC in a sequence: 70.
[hevc @ 0x563a20484500] Error parsing NAL unit #1.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[hevc @ 0x563a203a80a0] Could not find ref with POC 8102.62 bitrate=1598.6kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=2.14x    
[hevc @ 0x563a202fa9e0] Duplicate POC in a sequence: 82.
[hevc @ 0x563a202fa9e0] Error parsing NAL unit #1.
```

I am running driver 390.30.